# jquery find input value from string by input name

Tags: jquery

Hi i have string value of `<input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail[7835].ProductID" value=7835 /><input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail.Index" value="7835" />`

but when I run below to extract value from input, it just returns undefined ..

```
var stringVal = '<input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail[7835].ProductID" value=7835 /><input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail.Index" value="7835" />'
var inputVal = $('input[name="SaleDetail.Index"]', $(stringVal)).val();
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code would search for nested children element since there are no nested children it won't return any element. To get the element from a collection of element use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method instead.

```js
var stringVal = '<input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail[7835].ProductID" value=7835 /><input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail.Index" value="7835" />'
var inputVal = $(stringVal).filter('input[name="SaleDetail.Index"]').val();

console.log(inputVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or you need to wrap the elements by any other element to make it work.

```js
var stringVal = '<input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail[7835].ProductID" value=7835 /><input type="hidden" name="SaleDetail.Index" value="7835" />'
var inputVal = $('input[name="SaleDetail.Index"]', '<div>' + stringVal + '</div>').val();

console.log(inputVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```